# Which javascript library should I use?

Tags: javascript

I'll try to present my problem clearly, but I'm bit of a novice in programming so try to bear with me.

I'm currently working on a piece of map which I eventually need to get up and running on a website. I'm working on the file in Adobe Illustrator and I have several layers to the map. What I need is an intuitive, graphically pleasing, application where the user can pan and zoom in the map á la Google Maps. Another key feature I need is the ability to hide/show layers and being able to click on some of the highlighted points on one of these layers to bring up additional information. I've played around creating layer toggles straight in to an SVG but I really need them on a separate sidebar so they stay static when the user is eventually panning and zooming in to the map.

So far in to my research I've come to the conclusion that OpenLayers and Google Maps API are not for me as the map is relatively small and I don't need to tie it in to a larger map. Instead I think it's best to treat it as a biggish floating vector image.
I've also played around creating layer toggles straight in to an SVG but I really need them on a separate sidebar so they stay static when the user is eventually panning and zooming in to the map.
I tried working with Raphaël and while I especially like the graphical side of it, I'm struggling to work my Illustrator file in to it and the zooming/panning script I found isn't really working for me either.

So which way should I go? I apologize for my bad knowledge of things, but I'm quite lost here and would appreciate a nudge towards the right direction.

Thank you!
-Ilkka

Comment: if you are new to js, use [jquery](http://www.jquery.org), although you will be confuse when not using it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Raphael JS](http://raphaeljs.com/) is a very good Javascript vector-handling library, you may find it useful.
By the way, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571016/raphael-js-tutorial) has a link to a [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/an-introduction-to-the-raphael-js-library/) on it.

Answer (score 1):

There is [jVectorMap](http://jvectormap.owl-hollow.net/) for embedding vector maps into HTML pages, it has map zooming and moving functionality. I can help to convert your maps to the appropriate format (you need to extract svg pathes from source file).

Comment: @eugeneK Thanks. I'm going to add maps of the most world countries soon, working on converter form shapefiles to svg now.

Comment: Ok this looks promising, especially as it's a plugin for jQuery. I think one of my main problems right now is getting my vector image in to a format I could play around with in javascript. I understand that this should be relatively easy to do as SVG is simply XML. However, while I was playing with Raphael earlier I tried to simply open the SVG file in notepad and copying the path (after d="...) but nothing showed up. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For reference, this is what I tried to do with Raphaël

var testi=[0,0,500,500, {type:"path", path:"M59.084,70.08l91.045,73.632l19.403,43.781
  l-5.97,71.642l13.433,51.741c0,0-54.727,56.716-54.727,58.706s-38.309,19.9-38.309,19.9l-21.393-70.149L52.617,250l9.453-55.045
  l-9.453-33.333l-27.86-31.343L59.084,70.08z", "stroke-width":"3", stroke:"#000000", fill:"#00A651"}];

Comment: I tried to play around with it recreating the whole SVG-testfile I made just for practicing

http://jsfiddle.net/fpUYC/47/

is this looking alright? Can I just pretty much convert this in to jVectorMap?

Comment: The map itself can be easily converted to use with jVectorMap, but these animated circles are hard to do at the moment. I'll try to add some basic functionality for that today later.

Answer (score 0):

I think Dojo in conjunction with jQuery can give you nice results when working with HTML and SVG. Dojo is more kind of graphics JS library which works well with SVG and jQuery will allow you to work with HTML faster than most other JS frameworks

Comment: Dojo is a framework with a lot of functionality, Which part of dojo is the "graphic JS library" ?

Comment: It's integrated charting engine?

Comment: I guess their charting engine based on SVG manipulation so can be used out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

You should try **Raphael** by all means, perhabs in conjunction with jquery.
Using dojo sounds a bit like an overkill.